# Creating html elements and appending children using a for loop (or mapping?)

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to make a function which takes a string as input, creates several elements, then appends each element to the element previously created, so that the text is displayed as a list item, within a div, within a span.  The intent is to eventually make a basic to do list, but for now I'm stuck on the basic steps

I thought that a for loop could be useful for the creation of elements, though I can't figure out how to append what I have previously appended.  Here's how I started:

```
const elementsArray = [
                            'ol',
                            'li', 
                            'div',
                            'span',

                            ];

const makeToDoItem = (toDoItem) => {

    for (i = 0; i < elementsArray.length; i++) {

    const createElement = 
    document.createElement(elementsArray[i]);
    document.body.appendChild(createElement);
                     };
               };

makeToDoItem("post on stackoverflow");
```

I understand that

```
document.body.appendChild(createElement);
```

is doing what I am telling it to do: create four elements in the body.  How can I append them the way I would like to?

Is the .map function better for this?  I am having trouble grasping how to apply .map here.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: it's `document.body` not just `body`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const elementsArray = [
                            'ol',
                            'li'
                            ];

const makeToDoItem = (toDoItem) => {

    for (i = 0; i < elementsArray.length; i++) {

      const createElement = 
      document.createElement(elementsArray[i]);
      if (elementsArray[i] === 'li') {
        createElement.textContent = toDoItem;
      }
      document.body.appendChild(createElement);
    };
};

makeToDoItem("post on stackoverflow");
makeToDoItem("another post");
```

You can do the above but instead you probably want to create the <ol> in HMTL and then append <li> elements inside it.